# for cycle saving the last index instead of saving index by index

Tags: java, arrays, spring, for-loop, logic

I am new in java I have a problem the for cycle is not adding data to the List:

this is the code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model modl) throws TwitterException {
        
        // --------------------------------------------------
                // getTweets example
                // --------------------------------------------------
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                /*
                 * final TweetsResponse tweets = GetTweetsKt.getTweets(twitter, new
                 * long[]{1510021574505738201L}, null, null, null, null, null, "");
                 */

                /*
                 * userId: Long, endTime: Date? = null, exclude: String? = null, expansions:
                 * String? = null, maxResults: Int? = null, mediaFields: String? = null,
                 * paginationToken: String? = null, placeFields: String? = null, pollFields:
                 * String? = null, sinceId: Long? = null, startTime: Date? = null, tweetFields:
                 * String? = null, untilId: Long? = null, userFields: String? = null,
                 */

                long userId = 1510021146334437310L;
                Date endTime = null;
                String exclude = null;
                String expansions = null;
                int maxResults = 100;
                String mediaFields = null;
                String paginationToken = null;
                String placeFields = null;
                String pollFields = null;
                long sinceId = 1510021521342926810L;
                Date startTime = null;
                String tweetFields = null;
                long untilId = 1510022761187627010L;
                String userFields = null;

                final TweetsResponse tweets = TimelinesExKt.getUserTweets(twitter, userId, endTime, exclude, expansions,
                        maxResults, mediaFields, paginationToken, placeFields, pollFields, sinceId, startTime, tweetFields,
                        untilId, userFields);


                tweetModel tweetmodel = new tweetModel();
                List<tweetModel> tweetmodelList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < tweets.getTweets().size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.err.println("FOR TWEETS = " + tweets.getTweets().get(i).getText().toString());
                    tweetmodel.setTweets(tweets.getTweets().get(i).getText().toString());
                    this.tweetmodel2.setTweets(tweetmodel.getTweets().toString());
                    tweetmodelList.add(this.tweetmodel2);
                    System.err.println("TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::"+this.tweetmodel2.getTweets().toString());
                    System.err.println("//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets=="
                            + tweetmodel.getTweets().toString());
                    
                }
                
                for (int z = 0; z < tweetmodelList.size(); z++) {
                    
                    System.err.println(" ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== " + tweetmodelList.get(z).getTweets().toString());
                    

                
                
                }

        modl.addAttribute("tweetlists", tweetmodelList);

        return "index";
    }
```

this is the line of code where I set the data fetched by getTweets() function

```
tweetmodel.setTweets(tweets.getTweets().get(i).getText().toString());
                        this.tweetmodel2.setTweets(tweetmodel.getTweets().toString());
                        tweetmodelList.add(this.tweetmodel2);
```

the problem is that tweetmodelList is showing and recording the last recordset, I have 7 tweets and the function writes 7 times the last record, do not know what I am doing wrong, since

```
this.tweetmodel2.setTweets(tweetmodel.getTweets().toString());
                            tweetmodelList.add(this.tweetmodel2);
```

is inside the for cycle so it should iterate.... for example and for better understanding of what happens I will post here the results printed in the console

data in console HERE

```
FOR TWEETS = tweet 6
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::tweet 6
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets==tweet 6
1
2
3
4
5
6
FOR TWEETS = hello
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::hello
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets==hello
FOR TWEETS = cinco tweets
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::cinco tweets
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets==cinco tweets
FOR TWEETS = no
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::no
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets==no
FOR TWEETS = si
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::si
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets==si
FOR TWEETS = tweet number 3
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::tweet number 3
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets== tweet number 3
FOR TWEETS = tweet last
TWEETMODEL2::::::::::::::::tweet last
//////////////////TWEET MODEL HAVE THIS!!!!!!! tweetmodel.settweets==programar es mi tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== tweet last
 ====== TWEETS  IN TWEETMODELIST AFTER FIRST FOR tweetmodelList.add(tweetmodel); ======== 
tweet last
```

as you can see for some reason TWEETMODELIST only saves the last registry but saves the same the correct amount of tweets fetched which are 7 the problem is that as you can see, the other 7 tweets are different and are not being recorder or saved by the

```
tweetmodelList.add(this.tweetmodel2);
```

thanks in advance, the correct answer will be marked as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the next statements are executed inside the `for` loop:

```
tweetmodel.setTweets(tweets.getTweets().get(i).getText().toString());
this.tweetmodel2.setTweets(tweetmodel.getTweets().toString());
```

What it does is to replace the tweets collection of `tweetModel`, and then it replaces the tweets collection of `tweetModel2`.
But when you add `this.tweetmodel2` into `tweetmodelList` you're not adding the collection of tweets that holds `this.tweetmodel2`. Instead, you're adding the reference to `this.tweetmodel2` itself.

Then, after each iteration of the `for` loop, the instance of `this.tweetmode2` is the same, but its collection of tweets is not (becase its replaced with the new one). So, after 6 iterations you have only one instance of `this.tweetmode2` and the last tweets replaced. And that's why you see the last tweet printed out.

Since the `for` statement iterates 6 times, and you have the next statement inside, then it has added 6 elements into the variable `tweetmodelList`.

```
tweetmodelList.add(this.tweetmodel2); <-- adds the reference to variable tweetmodel2 into tweetmodelList 6 times
```

It can be fixed by creating and assigning a new instance to `this.tweetmodel2` like following:

```
tweetmodel.setTweets(tweets.getTweets().get(i).getText().toString());
this.tweetmodel2 = new TweetModel2(); <-- Create and assign a new instance
this.tweetmodel2.setTweets(tweetmodel.getTweets().toString());
tweetmodelList.add(this.tweetmodel2);
```